# Dart / Flutter sdk locations in IntelliJ Idea, is there a way to set them for a specific project?

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

Is there a way to set the Dart / Flutter sdk locations in IntelliJ Idea for a specific project?  I'm particularly interested in setting this for Flutter / Dart as I have different installed versions for different projects (I'm using fvm).

I know how to set them in the system preferences -> language & framesworks but this sets them for all projects.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is unanswered I figure it's better late than never...

It turns out when you set the SDK in system preferences, it is or individual projects, NOT for all projects. When you select the one from fvm, the global/system install of flutter is still available to select. There is also a little checkbox that allows you select/unselect whether that SDK is applied to your project or not. I'm using Intellij Ultimate. Maybe CE doesn't have that capability.